# How to merge two plots in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How can I merge box-plot and line plot in the same graph?
I have two data files. One for plotting box-plot and another for plotting line plot. Using these data files how can I plot box and line plot in a same graph.

Thanks in advance

```
set terminal pngcairo size  1024,768 enhanced font "Helvetica,15"
set output "filename"

unset log 
unset label
unset key

set style fill solid 0.0 border -1
set style boxplot outliers pointtype 7
set style data boxplot

set xrange [0 to 30]
set xtics ("0" 1, "5" 2, "10" 3, "15" 4, "20" 5, "25" 6, "27" 7, "29" 8, "30" 9) scale 0.0

set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror

set yrange [0 to 150]
set ytics 0,10,150
set title " "
set xlabel " "
set ylabel " "

plot for [i=1:9] 'file1' using (i):i notitle with boxplot lt -1, \
     'file2' with linespoints ls 1 ps 2 lw 2 lt rgb "blue"
```

Comment: `plot "file1" with boxes, "file2" with lines`

Comment: Hi, I tried with that. but x-axis is getting shrink.

Comment: `'file2' using 1:2`

Comment: No, Still getting same result

Comment: @Titu Please show your resulting graph and example data.